# Directx12 command list reset close memory leak

Tags: c++, graphics, memory, directx12

I simply reset and close the command list but my memory usage goes up 5 gb per second.

This is the simple list of things I do

1. Reset command buffer
2. Close command buffer
3. Reset command allocator

I feel like I'm missing something obvious with the way how dx12 works.

Any directions would be appreciated.

PS: Debugging layer does not throw any information or telling me something is off.

Edit 0 : This is the memory profile.
[image]
As you can see there is no component that causes my memory usage goes up.

This is how I reset-close my cmd list.

```
    void DX12CommandBuffer::LockCore()
    {
        ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(_cmdList->Reset(_ownerAllocator, nullptr)), "DX12CommandBuffer", "Failed to reset the command list");
    }
    void DX12CommandBuffer::UnlockCore()
    {
        ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(_cmdList->Close()), "DX12CommandBuffer", "Failed to close the command list");
    }
```

This is how I wait for for graphics device to finish

```
    void DX12Device::WaitForFinishCore()
    {
        const unsigned int fenceValue = _fenceValue;
        ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(_cmdQueue->Signal(_fence.Get(), fenceValue)), "DX12Device", "Command queue signalling failed!");

        _fenceValue++;

        if (_fence->GetCompletedValue() < fenceValue)
        {
            ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(_fence->SetEventOnCompletion(fenceValue, _fenceEvent)), "DX12Device", "Set event on completion failed!");

            WaitForSingleObject(_fenceEvent, INFINITE);
        }

        ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(_cmdAllocator.Reset()),"DX12Device","Couldnt reset the command allocator");

        LOG("DX12Device", "Fence value %d", _fenceValue);
    }
```

There is literally no other operations runs between them and the ordering is same in the program's execution. Reset->Close->Wait for device

I have implented the setting up the render targets for clearing the color targets. I have successfully cleared the color of the swapchain backbuffers and swapped them. The memory usage is dropped from 5 gb/s to 2 mb/s with this setup. This is interesting. I dont know whats going on here

Comment: Are you doing anything else, like setting up geometry to draw, shader programs or textures to draw with?

Comment: Nope literally nothing. I remove the command list reset and close section of the code and my memory usage stays stable at 75mb. It goes up as soon as I enable command list reset and close methods.

Comment: Try adding a Present. DirectX 12 does 'deferred object destruction' so it's just not cleaning up your orphan objects as fast as you are creating them.  For basic render loops, see [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/tree/main/d3d12game_win32).